# Is it possible to add Shopify app to already existing Ruby on Rails web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I want to integrate my web app with Shopify which means I have to create my own Shopify app. I noticed that Shopify requires self hosting so it would benefit me to add the Shopify app as part of my already existing web app because I can host it together.

Does this seem possible or do I have to make a desperate application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should totally be possible to add a shopify app to your existing ruby on rails project.

If you look at https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app all you have to do is add in  `shopify_app` to your gem file and then generate the proper routes. You can use their built-in generators or manually make the routes yourself.

Basically you would just need to make additional routes for your existing application to handle the requests to and from Shopify.

Comment: Thanks so much Charles this will save me a lot of time

Comment: What routes should I generate myself? I cannot use the built in generator because it generates tables that I don't need